# Dockerfile change usergroup without logout/login

Tags: docker, ubuntu, authentication, dockerfile, logout

In Docker file I have this

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt update && apt -y upgrade
RUN apt install -y sudo
# Setup ops user use defaults uid 1000 gid 1000
RUN useradd -d /home/myuser -aG sudo \
    && usermod -aG sudo root \ 
    && echo "%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers
```

when execute

```
docker run -dit -u 1000:1000 myimage "/bin/bash"
docker exec -it 23u898908 "/bin/bash"
```

I get

```
myuser@23u898908$ id 
uid=1000(myuser) gid=1000(myuser) groups=1000(myuser)

myuser@23u898908$ id myuser
uid=1000(myuser) gid=1000(myuser) groups=1000(myuser),27(sudo)

myuser@23u898908$ sudo ls
file.txt
```

in other words, the groups are working, but not showing in the `id` command, but show in the `id myuser` command, just curious if there is something I am missing, or is it by design?
if executed

```
myuser@23u898908$sudo su -l myuser
$id
uid=1000(myuser) gid=1000(myuser) groups=1000(myuser),27(sudo)
```

expected behaviour is to show all groups with just the `id` command, is this a bug maybe??

Comment: If you want a user with unrestricted privileges, try running it as `USER root` or `docker run -u 0`.  The setup you have where the user can do literally anything so long as they remember to say `sudo` first isn't especially more secure than just being root.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the reason I want to have a local user with root privileges, is that I am running this container as my development workstation, and my host machine Ubuntu with GUI interface uses VScode, so the common ground between them is to run the contianer as "non-root" user so that any modification in the mounted volumes will be reported as the container owner not the root, so I run the container with -u 1000:1000 and that gives the outcome I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

you must relogin or restart container to refresh it. id takes it for current session

Comment: Thanks for the response, you mean by restarting the container, by docker rm ... and then docker run again? I already done that. unless something else in mine. multiple docker exec won't help either. remember the usrmod are in the Dockerfile not in the session.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Basically there is a need to terminate the bash session and re-establish it again by adjusting the above commands in Dockerfile by adding `exit` at the end of last shell command, that will enforce a new bash session to be kicked off.

```
RUN useradd -d /home/myuser -aG sudo \
    && usermod -aG sudo root \ 
    && echo "%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers && exit
USER myuser
WORKDIR /home/myuser
```

Now when I do docker run -dit myimage "/bin/bash"
I get the $ prompt and $id produces the expected results.
The catch is, there is no need to use --user 1000:1000 on the docker run command.